# timestamp in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
+---+---+----+
| ts| p1| p2 |
+---+---+------
|200|[1]| null|
|220|[2]| [2] |
|240|[3]| [4] |
|250|[3]| [4] |
+---+---+-----+
```

I need an output like this:

```
+---+---+----+
| ts_new| p1| p2 |
+---+---+------
|200|[1]| null|
|200|[2]| [2] |
|230|[3]| [4] |
|230|[3]| [4] |
+---+---+-----+
```

Basically I need a function which takes an input of ts say 200, and then at every interval of 30 units, replaces the value of ts if it is in the interval of 30 units.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```py
binsize = 30
offset = 200
df["ts"] = ((df["ts"] - offset) // binsize) * binsize + offset
```

Comment: Thanks Alex this worked, i did an iterative approach which took longer, yours is a better solution. appreciate your help